# Multiple mirror pages with "/"

Tags: html, http, web, centos, mirror

I have the following issue:

Domain is example.com and a url example.com/something.php
Whenever I add a / at the end of any url I have a mirror page.
Example:
example.com/something.php/   is mirror of example.com/something.php

Thats bad because it caused many soft 404 error pages in my webmaster tools.

Moreover, I noticed the following.

URL A: example.com/something.php 
URL B: example.com/something2.php

I'm trying to access example.com/something.php/something2.php
and it replies me with a mirror of example.com/something.php . Why it doesn't reply me a 404 error page??

this is too wrong and causes me many problems with the crawlers. Google send in my webmaster tools messages about that. He told me that I have more thatn 900000 soft error pages. My site has only 200 pages.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebuild your apache.That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on your web server configuration. It could be something in your .htaccess, your Apache httpd.conf, etc. Have you ever visited them and seen anything that may redirect to a page?

Comment: I visited them, and url shows me a root file.

eg.  example.com/some1.php/some2.php/some3.php/  -> is example.com/some1.php/  it didnt redict, but the content is from some1.php file